# NavigationView click listener not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

> I am trying to handle **NavigationView click listener for back button** but it is not working.

`navigationView.setOnClickListener` may be enough but may be it's due to some other reason that's why added full class

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        resetActionBar();

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        navigationView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
                    onBackPressed();
            }
        });
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE).replace(R.id.content_fragment, new CameraFragment()).commit();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        //super.onBackPressed();
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == android.R.id.home)
        {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
                onBackPressed();
            else
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(navigationView);
            return  true;
        }else if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment = null;

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
            fragment = new CameraFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            fragment = new GalleryFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            fragment = new SlideShowFragment();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if(fragment!=null){

            if(item.isChecked())
            {
                if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()==0){
                    drawer.closeDrawers();
                }else{
                    removeAllFragments();
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE).replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment).commit();
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }

            }else{
                removeAllFragments();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_CLOSE).replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment).commit();
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        }


        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void removeAllFragments(){
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null,
                FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }

    public void replaceFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .replace(R.id.content_fragment, fragment).addToBackStack("")
                .commit();
    }

    public void updateDrawerIcon() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Log.i("", "BackStackCount: " + getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount());
                    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
                        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
                    else
                        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, 50);
    }

    public void resetActionBar()
    {
        //display home
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    public void setActionBarTitle(String title) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

**Answer found by Mike M Comment:**

remove `navigation.setOnClickListener` and replace it to

```
toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0)
                        onBackPressed();
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is not working and what are you trying to do? 'onBackPressed' method already handles back button, where you close the drawer layout if it is open and call super if it is closed.

Comment: Setting an `OnClickListener` on the entire `NavigationView` doesn't really make sense. Please better explain what you're attempting.